# Parse Junit xml file

Tags: xml, junit, xml-parsing, report

Is there any open source libraries to parse junit xml using java and get information like testsuite name that are executed ,testcases corresponding to a testsuite , number of failures and number of success ? I just saw [junit style report tool](http://www.soapui.org/Reporting/junit-style-html-reports.html) , is there any open source libraries to get these information in java.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **junitreport** task from ant to generate some report files which shows the informations you need. Also check the question [Custom JUnit Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1727616/286934) on how to customize the generated report for your needs.