# Customizing and adding more information to junit results

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit-runner

I have junit test cases with a unique id mentioned in method documentation. For example, in the following test cases is XNH233T

```
/**
* XNH233T
**/
@Test
public void testAPlusB(){
}
```

Now, how I can write the ID of each test cases to test results ? 
I know there is a way to [customize results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727616/custom-junit-report). I like to add a child node to each test tag in the results, e.g.

```
<test duration="1811" status="passed" name="testAPlusB"/>
...
<id >
XNH233T
</id>
...
</test>
```

I am not too familiar with how junit reports are generated. It would be great if some one can suggest on how to achieve above task.

Comment: I customize the junit test runner to write custom information to results. It works!