# How to filter the contents of xml formatter in ant junit task?

Tags: junit, ant, formatter

I am integrating junit test cases with my current project that uses ant build files. I have added a few test cases, and they are running perfectly as part of build process. I need to generate a detailed and relevant report of junit along with build. Inside `<junit>`, I am using `<formatter>`. I am facing following issues:

1. If I use `<formatter type="plain">`, it contains very limited information.
2. If I use `<formatter type="xml>`, it prints too many properties.
3. I tried writing a custom formatter using `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitResultFormatter`. For this, I need to add `ant-x.x.x.jar` and `ant-junit-x.x.x.jar` in build file `<classpath>`. It gives "two different ant versions are present"

**Question-1:**
Is there any way by which we can restrict or filter the XML elements to be printed in reports, maybe by overriding XML formatter or some other way?

**Question-2:** How can I avoid the above exception of "two different ant version"?

I would prefer if there is some option for question-1.

**[UPDATE-1] My JUnit task in Ant:**

```
<target name="unit_testing" depends="binary" description="Unit Testing">
        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build_main} -->
        <javac srcdir="${codebase_test}" destdir="${build_test}"
            encoding="cp1252" includeantruntime="false"
            bootclasspath="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.5.0_07/jre/lib/rt.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.5.0_07/jre/lib/rt.jar;"
            source="1.5" target="1.5">
            <classpath refid="classpath_main" />
            <classpath refid="classpath_test" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${binary}/binary_x.x.x.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
            <!-- set useFile="true" if output required in files -->
            <formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />

            <classpath refid="classpath_main" />
            <classpath refid="classpath_test" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${build_test}" />
                <pathelement location="${binary}/binary_x.x.x.jar" />
            </classpath>

            <batchtest todir="${results_test}">
                <fileset dir="${build_test}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.class" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>

        </junit>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1

Consider using the [`<xslt>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) to take the XML files generated by `<junit>` as input and use XSLT to generate another XML file as output.

See [Custom JUnit Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727616/custom-junit-report/1733940#1733940) for an example of using XSLT to generate other files.

### Question 2

There shouldn't be a need to specify either `ant-x.x.x.jar` or `ant-junit-x.x.x.jar` on the `<classpath>` passed to `<junit>`.

By default, `includeantruntime` is `true` for `<junit>`. That means `ant-x.x.x.jar` and `ant-junit-x.x.x.jar` will already be on the CLASSPATH given to forked JUnit processes.

Removing `ant-x.x.x.jar` and `ant-junit-x.x.x.jar` from `<classpath>` will avoid the `multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit` warning.

Comment: `includeantruntime` was `false` in my file. Will try by setting it `true`. I didn't get the first answer. I have never used `XSTL` so how to use `junitreport` or `XSTL` in ant file? I have updated my ant code in question.

Comment: I am able to get reports in frames and the system properties ... will try with  custom XSTL...

Comment: At many places, I have seen `@*|b/@*`, what does `b/@*` mean in that?

Comment: @AmberBeriwal `b/@*` means "match the attributes of elements named `<b>`. For example, in the XML fragment `<a a1="foo"/><b b1="foo"/><b b2="bar"/><c c1="baz"/>`, `b/@*` matches the `b1` and `b2` attributes of the two `<b>` elements.

Comment: OK..Now I get it....thanks buddy...your answer really helped me out to get a quick result.