# How can i attach screenshots in surefire report?

Tags: selenium, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I can generate the surefire-report and I can take test's screenshots. Is there something that i can do to generate the surefire-report with screenshots? Or create a link in the report to the screenshots?

Thanks!

Comment: First not enough information about your context? What kind of screenshots? Unit tests do not make any screenshot?

Comment: for junit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727616/custom-junit-report for testng https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/customized-testng-emailable-report2